# I want to ask questions. A better reputation scoring is needed

Tags: feature-request, moderation, moderators

This is a duplicate, but answers may vary do to each individual SE policy.

I have a positive reputation in science and math there are negatives. I thought I was OK but now I cannot ask questions or revise on poor(which is an opinion of a few not of the many) questions.

The rules are defined, but the most important rules not stated, like how many votes can one person give to another? How many "questions received poorly" can be asked before restriction. I don't need to know. I know those now, after it's too late. I can change/hide my IP and Email easier than tampering with questions that have an answer.

**Why can't upgrades be made to this system for one user to block another if they are bored and/or annoyed by the questioner thus allowing lower lever users to answer questions for them? 
Is it software design or software limitation?**

Comment: Why does your reputation on other Stack Exchange sites (or even on this site) matter?  The banning algorithm (which is secret) may be slightly influenced by reputation, but for the most part your reputation points seems to be irrelevant to your current situation.  Ask enough bad questions and you'll be banned from asking more even if you have 100,000 points.

Answer (score 5):

Although [we don't like](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3103/14897) changing questions after being answered (different from accepted), [I did update my answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/31371/14897) to reflect your changes.

The problem is you are not solving one problem at a time, you are creating a bunch of them and asking us to point them out.

I said before high imagination is not bad, but it's not engineering. The ideas are cool and I think are suited for [WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

In the help center there is a section on how to write a good question. Try to show what problem you are facing (not what problems we should find).

Also try to [punctuate the sentences](http://www.bbc.co.uk/skillswise/topic/punctuation), I have hard time understanding your post here on meta, and [SE generally advises](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to not invest time when the question is not clear.

---

- If the one problem boils down to how to carry a payload into space using only electricity, then it's not on-topic here.
- If the problem is how big of a payload can an electrically powered plane carry, then it has been answered before here IIRC.
- If the problem is how to suspend rails, or drag a cable into space, then again it is not on-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

You're asking several questions here, which I'll try to address.

> The rules are defined, but the most important rules not stated.

The most important rules are about how to ask a good question, which is what you didn't follow and got you banned.  Additionally, the question banning policy is prominently stated in the [help centre](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), and the first time you were banned for a week this link should have appeared for you. Normally I'm opposed to the assumption that users have read a lot of the meta pages and blog posts, but this is not the case here.  Your situation could have been avoided by following the information on some of the most prominent pages on the help centre like ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) or ["Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited).  I'm sorry if this came as a surprise to you, but you are expected to put in a a enough time to understand a few basic rules, especially when you're asked to improve your questions.

> How many "questions received poorly" can be asked before restriction.

As explained on the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/) linked in the [ban explanation page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), "The details of this algorithm have to be kept vague, because we don’t want people to game it or exploit it."

> how many votes can one person give to another?

What was unclear about this and why is it so important to you? This is listed in the FAQ for stack exchange listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

> Why can't upgrades be made to this system for one user to block another if they are bored and/or annoyed by the questioner thus allowing lower lever users to answer it for them?

This would imply that the quality standards on this site are personal and arbitrary and that questions that are hard to answer are OK for some people but not for others. This is not the case.  For example, say you ask a "why not" question about plausibility of a novel idea that defies several airplane-building principles. Having that question looked at by a different person doesn't suddenly make it a thoroughly researched and clear question with a fact-based answer.

Just to be clear, you weren't banned from asking questions because one or two people took a personal issue with your questions.  Most of your closed questions were closed by completely different sets of people, indicated a large consensus that your questions could use improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple questions here and it's a hard to understand what some of them are, but you seem to be concerned with:

- what restrictions are there on voting
- how do question bans work
- why can't users be blocked, could the software be changed to allow it

None of these are specific to Aviation.SE, they apply to all SE sites.  If you want to understand why SE software works the way it does and want to suggest changes, you need to read a lot of background information on meta.SE and then post questions there.